# How to display Model data in a Django Template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am new to Django. I am trying to display data from my Project model in my index view, using a template. I tried my best to structure this app similar to the polls app. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. I am using python 2.7, and django 1.8.6

Here is my url:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

app_name = 'project'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
]
```

Here is my Model:

```
import datetime
from django.db import models
from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils import timezone


@python_2_unicode_compatible  # only if you need to support Python 2
class Contractor(models.Model):
    #project
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=14, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='Contractor_created_by')
    created_date = models.DateTimeField()
    modified_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='Contractor_modified_by')
    modified_date = models.DateTimeField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

@python_2_unicode_compatible  # only if you need to support Python 2
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    jobNumber = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    shopOut = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    shopIn = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    delivery = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    job1 = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    job2 = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    job3 = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    contractor = models.ForeignKey(Contractor, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=101)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='Project_created_by')
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='Project_modified_by')
    modified_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.created_by = User.objects.get(id=1)
            self.modified_by = User.objects.get(id=1)
            super(Project, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
            year = datetime.datetime.now().year
            self.jobNumber = '{}{:04d}'.format(year, self.id)
        self.modified_by = User.objects.get(id=1)
        super(Project, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Here is my View:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.views import generic
from django.utils import timezone

from .models import Project

# Create your views here.
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    model = Project
    template_name = 'project/index.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Project.objects

class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Project
```

Here is my Template:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<h1>Projects</h1>
<ul>
{% for projects in project.get_queryset %}
    in for loop
    <!-- <li><a href="{% url 'projects:detail' projects.id %}">{{ projects.name }}</a></li> -->
    <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
{% endfor %}

</ul>
end of list
```

When I go to the page I get a h1 Project, an empty ul, and a line that says 'end of list'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `get_queryset`, you should return `Project.objects.all()`.

In your template, you don't need to do `project.get_queryset`, the `get_queryset` method is called for you and the values are passed to the template as `object_list` and `<objectname>_list`, along with other parameters. In your case, the object is `Project` so there should be a `project_list` variable too along with `object_list`.

You can do:

```
{% for project in project_list %}
    <li><a href="{% url 'projects:detail' project.id %}">{{ project.name }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

Or:

```
{% for project in object_list %}
    <li><a href="{% url 'projects:detail' project.id %}">{{ project.name }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

You can read more about it here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview

Comment: You could at least explain why the op should return that queryset,.. I didn't check to see what you missed out of Shang Wangs answer

Comment: In addition to Shang Wang's answer, I explained how the queryset is handled in a ListView and the two possible ways to iterate over the object list.

Answer (score 2):

Your get queryset doesn't return a query set at the minute, currently its just returning a related manager. you should make it return a queryset...

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return Project.objects.all()  # added all
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try:

```
{% for project in object_list %}
    <li><a href="{% url 'projects:detail' project.id %}">{{ project.name }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

`object_list` is the default name of queryset if you use `ListView`, you can change that by defining `context_object_name` in your view. Here's [django doc about that](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#making-friendly-template-contexts).