# Diplay object list, not working

Tags: django, django-models

I guess that I will ask a very simple question, but it is a sign that I still do not get something. 
I have a team model and I would like to display a list of all the team that the logged in user created.

I tried with

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block body %}
<div class="container">

    <div class="jumbotron">
      <h2>Select one of your team and link it to your project</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        {% for i  in team_set.all %}
          <p>{{ i.team_name }}</p>
        {% endfor %}

    </div>


</div>

{% endblock %}
```

But first it does not display anything and it is suppose to show all the team and not only the teams that the current logged in user created.

COuld you please give me a hand ?

model.py :

```
class Team(models.Model):
    team_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default = '')
    team_hr_admin = models.ForeignKey(MyUser, blank=True, null=True)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(MyUser, related_name="members")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.team_name
```

view.py:

```
class LinkTeam(TemplateView):
    template_name= 'link_project.html'
```

url.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from website import views

app_name = 'website'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^hr_index/$', views.HRIndex.as_view(), name='hr_index'),
    url(r'^addproject/$', views.ProjectCreate.as_view(), name='add_project'),
    url(r'^addteam/$', views.TeamCreate.as_view(), name='add_team'),
    url(r'^linkteam/$', views.LinkTeam.as_view(), name='Link_team'),
    url(r'^project/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$',views.ProjectDetailView.as_view(), name='ProjectDetails'),
]
```

Comment: show the view...

Comment: without view how can you access the model data ???

Comment: Please edit your answer with models, view, url and html template that you are trying..

Comment: done ...........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply, you can try this

***in the View***

```
class LinkTeam(TemplateView):

    template_name= 'link_project.html'

    def get(request):
         courts = Yourmodel.objects.all()          # worth looking into?

         return render_to_response(self.template_name, {'courts': courts})
```

***AND in HTML:***

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
    {% for i  in courts %}
      <p>{{ i.team_name }}</p>
    {% endfor %}

</div>
```

Comment: I get : get() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: try def get(self, request):

Comment: worked ! ;) thx ! How would you do the same using ListView do you know ?

Comment: glad it helped you. you can always upvote :)  about list view, you can check this  
               https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35071257/how-to-display-model-data-in-a-django-template