# Django: Read child objects from parent object effectively

Tags: python, django, parent-child

I am fairly new to django and want to know the most effective way to go about my requirement here. I am creating a project tracking app, where a single project can have many team members and clientteam members and also multiple feedbacks. I have a table for team members and clientteam individually, but I also want to track the role of each team member within a project.

I tried the following model structure using a mapping table, but now I am struggling to fetch data from it to django template.

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse


class Project(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=300)

    primary_contact1 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    primary_contact2 = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField() 

    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    date_last_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('project-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})


class Teammember(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name + " " + self.last_name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('teammember-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})


class ProjectTeam(models.Model):
    project_team_member = models.ForeignKey(Teammember, related_name="project_team_member", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, related_name="project_team_project", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    project_role = models.CharField(max_length=50)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.project.title + " - " + self.project_team_member.first_name + " - " + self.project_role


class Timesheet(models.Model):
    week_start_date = models.DateField()
    week_hours = models.IntegerField()

    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, related_name="ts_project", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    project_team_member = models.ForeignKey(Teammember, related_name="ts_project_team_member", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.project.title + " - " + self.project_team_member.first_name + " - " + self.week_start_date.strftime('%b/%d/%Y') + " - " + str(self.week_hours)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('timesheet-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

class Clientteam(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    designation = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    assigned_lead = models.ForeignKey(Teammember, related_name="assigned_lead", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    lead_generator = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="lead_generator", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    date_last_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name + " " + self.last_name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('clientteam-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})


class ProjectClientTeam(models.Model):
    project_clientteam_member = models.ForeignKey(Clientteam, related_name="project_clientteam_member", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, related_name="project_client_team_project", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    project_role = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.project.title + " - " + self.project_client_teammember.first_name + " - " + self.project_role


class Feedback(models.Model):
    overall_score = models.IntegerField()
    overall_desc = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    date_received = models.DateTimeField()

    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, related_name="feedback_project", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    clientteam = models.ForeignKey(Clientteam, related_name="feedback_clientteam", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.project.title + " - " + self.clientteam.first_name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('feedback-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

In the template, I am looping over projects and showing all its field and want to loop over all teammembers and client team members for a given project. I tried the following syntax but it does not show any data:

```
{% for proj_m in projects.project_client_team_member_set.all %}
                                    <li><a class="article-text" href="{% url 'clientteam-detail' proj_m.id %}">{{ proj_m.first_name }} {{ proj_m.last_name }}</a> ( {{ proj_m.project_role }} )</li>
                                {% endfor %}
```

Can be model structure be more effective somehow in my case here? If not what am I missing here to directly access the child records from parent?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35071257/how-to-display-model-data-in-a-django-template

Comment: Hi hazmat, thanks for sharing the post, however, it is a bit different from my requirement here, I am able to fetch the direct columns from my project table, its the child model columns I want to access in template.

Comment: The reverse relation `project_client_team_member_set` has not been defined anywhere in your models.

Comment: Can you please share an example for defining the same in models?
I have tried defining the related_name property for each ForeignKey relation

Comment: You use `related_name`, like you have done in other places. But I see that you do not even have a foreign key relationship between `Projects` and `Clientteam`.

Comment: I have tried using a mapping table between projects and clientteam as ProjectClientTeam, wherein I've defined the foreign relationship between both, as I also have to maintain a role for each clientteam related to a projcet.
Can this be done any other way more efficiently?